# HTTP error 500, not sure where to start

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $tabel = array();
    $teller = 0;
    $handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/images/bbq2015/');
        while($file = readdir($handle)){
            if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
                $tabel[$teller] = $file;
                $teller++;
            }
        }

        $n = $tabel.length();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $n-1; $i++)
        for ($j = 0; $j < $n-$i-1; $j++)
            if ($tabel[$j] > $tabel[$j+1])
            {
                $temp = $tabel[$j];
                $tabel[$j] = $tabel[$j+1];
                $tabel[$j+1] = $temp;
            }
        $teller = 0;
        while($teller < $n){
            echo '<a class="example-image-link" href="images/bbq2015/'.$tabel[$teller].'" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="BBQ 2015"><img class="halloween2015" src="images/bbq2015/'.$tabel[$teller].'"/></a>';
            $teller++;

        }
?>
```

I realise that this might not be the best code but I'm trying.
I would love to know where I'm making an error, not looking for my code fixed.

Comment: Probably start with error reporting?

Comment: You can wait for some time someone will come a long post an answer saying please add a `$` to  `$n = tabel.length();` and will get quite some up-votes with *wow great* comments and will still be wrong :P

Comment: Yup my guess is here $n = tabel.length();

Comment: @HankyPanky That would indeed help, but after changing that It still doesn't show anything..

Comment: Yep because that is JS, in PHP you would do `$n=count($arrayName);`

Comment: `ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the second line under `<?php` and post the results of executio

Comment: @HankyPanky Thanks, but I guess there is still more wrong code in there..

Comment: what happens when you hardcode the path of `$handle`?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? All these loops overwriting your variables seem needlessly complicated.

Comment: @HankyPanky The final upload didn't go through after changing the count it works like a charm! Thanks you so much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change

```
$n= $tabel.length(); //there is no length() function in PHP
```

to

```
$n= count($tabel);
```

> count() returns the number of elements in an array.